# Java : How to access attribute from an interface method

Tags: java, methods, interface, attributes

I create an interface as follow :

```
// The OnClickListener interface :
public interface OnClickListener{

    void onClick(); 

}
```

And a I create a Person Class :

```
// Class Person :
public class Person
{
    String name;

    OnClickListener onClicklisner;

    Person(String name) 
    {   
        this.name = name;

        this.onClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
        {      
           @Override
            public void onClick() {

                //I want to access to this.name attribute, but it doesn't work :
                System.out.println(this.name);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In the onClick() method above, I want to access to this.name attribute, but it doesn't work.

How I can access that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//I want to access to this.name attribute, but it doesn't work :
  System.out.println(this.name);
```

here `this` refers to `OnClickListener` object which doesn't have `name`

Use `name` instead of `this.name` as below,

```
this.onClicklisner = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick() {

        //I want to access to this.name attribute, but it doesn't work :
        System.out.println(name);
    }
};
```

Comment: This is good, but if the `name` field changes, it won't work. You should either declare the field as final, or rename the parameter `name` to `nom` or something, I think

Answer (score 4):

You should prefix it with the class name `Person.this.name`

Answer (score 2):

pbaris's approach of `Person.this.name` works, but you can also make a getter and use `getName()` or, if you declare the field `name` final, you can use `name` directly without a prefix.

You can also use a lambda expression, since your interface is a functional interface

```
this.onClickListener = () -> System.out.println(this.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen into a common scope trap in Java, and this approach defeats the purpose of interfaces. On the following line of code you instantiate an anonymous class:

```
this.onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
// We are now in the scope of the anonymous class implementing the OnClickListener interface.
}
```

As pbaris's answer suggests, you could use `Person.this.name` to reference the parent object's attributes, but that couples your code to the `Person` class and defeats the purpose of having a separate class implement the `OnClickListener` interface. You could either have the `Person` class implement the interface, or declare a new class that implements the interface and takes a reference to `Person` as a constructor argument:

```
public class  PersonClickedListener implements OnClickListener {

    private Person parent;    

    public PersonClickedListener(Person parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        System.out.println(parent.name);
    }
}
```

Then, in `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    String name;

    OnClickListener onClicklistener;

    Person(String name) 
    {   
        this.name = name;

        this.onClickListener = new PersonClickedListener();
    }
}
```

You could get even fancier and have `Person` implement an interface that exposes a `getName()` method, that way your `PersonClickedListener` could work for any class that implements that new interface.